# takeWhile arguments between pipe symbol - |

Tags: haskell, pipe

takeWhile (or) `dropWhile` takes a predicate as their argument. What is the first argument `|Int x->Bool|`, that `takeWhile` asks? What does `pipe` symbol mean in haskell?

```
foo := [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
bar := foo.takeWhile |Int x->Bool| { return x < 3 }
// bar == [1, 2]
baz := foo.dropWhile |Int x->Bool| { return x < 3 }
// baz == [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this?  Because that is not Haskell syntax.

Comment: http://fantom.org/forum/topic/401

Comment: For one thing, Haskell doesn't use `:=` for defining things, just `=`, the `|` symbol is usually reserved for guards, which this definitely isn't.  `return x < 3` is parsed as `(return x) < 3`, so it would have to be returning into a monad that implements `Ord` and `Num`, and I don't know any monads that implement `Num`.  Haskell also uses `--` for comments, not the C style `//`.  The `foo.takeWhile` syntax is new to me too, it would normally be `takeWhile predicate foo`, the use of `.` here would mean function composition, and `foo` isn't a function.

Comment: That's [Fantom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_%28programming_language%29), a completely different language.  The author of that post is comparing the language to Haskell and talking about features they miss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the direct translation into Haskell would look like this:

```
module SO where

foo :: [Int]
foo = [1,2,3,4,5]

bar :: [Int]
bar = takeWhile (\x -> x < 3) foo

baz :: [Int]
baz = dropWhile (\x -> x < 3) foo
```

here is a sample output in GHCi:

```
λ> foo
[1,2,3,4,5]
λ> bar
[1,2]
λ> baz
[3,4,5]
```

I guess `|Int x -> Bool| { return x < 3 }` is the syntax for a lambda in Fantom - and so the translation of your **predicate** into Haskell is just

```
\x -> x < 3
```

As you see Haskell does not need the type annotations (the part between your **pipes** `|`) here - it will be able to infer it.

Indeed you would not need the types at all - but typically you'll give them for top level constructs in modules.

### it's more generic

Indeed although this all was just for `Int` lists Haskell can make the same code work for all sorts of numbers.

As you are using number literals (the `3`) and the binary operator `<` inside your *predicate* you need two constraints here:

- `Num` for the numbers you are using
- `Ord` for the `<`

GHCi will tell you as much:

```
λ> :t (\x -> x < 3)
(\x -> x < 3) :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool
```

This is why you could also write more generically:

```
foo :: Num a => [a]
foo = [1,2,3,4,5]

bar :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a]
bar = takeWhile (\x -> x < 3) foo

baz :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a]
baz = dropWhile (\x -> x < 3) foo
```

also.